# Unrecognized selector error caused by didSet in @IBOutlet of NSTextView

Tags: swift

I am creating a window covering the entire screen of the main display using the following code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      
    // start hidden then show the screen after moving to the main screen
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //keep the window top
        self.view.window?.level = .floating
        
        
        //set up the main display as the display where the window shows up
        let screens = NSScreen.screens
        var pos = NSPoint()
        pos.x = screens[0].visibleFrame.midX
        pos.y = screens[0].visibleFrame.midY
        self.view.window?.setFrameOrigin(pos)
        
        
        self.view.window?.zoom(self)
        self.view.window?.level = .floating
        //self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        
        
        //stop the user from moving the window
        self.view.window?.isMovable = false
        //disable resizable mode
        self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
        self.view.window?.setIsVisible(true)
    }
    
   //set up font for the reflectionForm
   reflectionForm.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)

   //other code
```

However, when I want to change the font of the `NSTextView` of screen (`reflectionForm.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)`), the app crashes saying:

> hread 1: "-[NSScrollView setFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14485d800"

I found one strange thing that relates to this error. I am trying to connect the content `NSTextView` with a static variable. When I deleted `didSet`, the app works fine. I have an idea what is going on.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {
//other code
    static var reflectionFormViewerContent: String = ""
@IBOutlet var reflectionForm: NSTextView!{
    didSet{
        ViewController.reflectionFormViewerContent = reflectionForm.string
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solveing this problem.

Comment: I think as you are calling the adding method on viewdidload. The instance is not set to reflectionForm textView. Try setting these in viewdidappear or viewdidlayoutsubviews. But I will prefer viewdidappear as the viewdidlayoutsubview will call many times in the same screen whenever layout is updated.

Comment: Thank you, @MayankVerma! I created the `ViewDidAppear` and put `//set up font for the reflectionForm
       reflectionForm.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)` and other codes there. However, now a small blank window shows up and I am getting an error " Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): -[NSScrollView string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136853400"  and " -[NSScrollView string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136853400". Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you add an exemption breakpoint and check what is causing the issue of unrecognized selector sent to instance ?

Comment: The error seems to be in the middle of the didSet of `reflectionForm`. (`@IBOutlet var reflectionForm: NSTextView!    {
        didSet{
            reflectionFormViewerContent = reflectionForm.string
        }
    }` (Come to think of this, this is kinda bizarre because I have another `NSTextField!` using didSet there too, but no error is happening there. (`@IBOutlet weak var finishedNumberViewer: NSTextField!{
        didSet{
            self.finishedNumberViewer.stringValue = "Compleated Number: " + Counter.description
        }
    }`

Comment: Do you understand that all the code _after_ your DispatchQueue.main.async curly braces runs _before_ all the code _inside_ your DispatchQueue.main.async curly braces?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @matt. To be honest, I only vaguely understand what `DispatchQueue.main.async` does. I used this because, without it, the fullscreen function did not work, and found this `DispatchQueue.main.async` trick online somewhere. Do you think this could be causing the problem? If so, could you help me recode this right?

Comment: I have no clue what's going on because you have not shown enough code — just some snippets with no context. Try to write a complete self contained [mcve].

Comment: Thank you, @matt, for the suggestion of creating a mini reproducible example! While creating it, I realized that there is no problem; and then solved this problem by just replacing the old textview with new one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest that the text view outlet in the storyboard might be faulty.

Comment: I have never thought of that. You saved my day! I hope you have a good one, @matt. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem simply by deleting the old `textview` and creating a new `textview`.

For those who face with the same problem, it may be worth trying it.